# How to install AWS CLI in docker container based on image “java:8”

Tags: docker, java-8, dockerfile, aws-cli

I have a Dockerfile that is like:

```
FROM java:8

LABEL maintainer="CMS"


RUN apt-get install python-pip
RUN pip install awscli
....
.....
```

**[Error: Unable to locate package python-pip]**

My end goal is to have java8 and aws-cli installed. Also I don't want to use curl statements in the Dockerfile. Also I don't want to use the plain ubuntu image.

How should I go about doing it?

Comment: Are you actually looking for the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)?  Why would you need the AWS CLI tools in a pure-Java application?

Answer (score 1):

The error says Pip is not installed. Try installing it properly. If installed try executing same commands to verify.

Comment: What is meant by `properly`? That is why I am asking for help here as I am not able to do it `properly`

Comment: Follow official pip installation, tell what error comes if you try it. Download manually from https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files

Answer (score 0):

try to update your docker file to

```
FROM java:8

LABEL maintainer="CMS"


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.4 \
    python3-pip

RUN pip install awscli
....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to base it on top of openjdk:8 image, try the following:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN set -eux; \
        apt-get update; \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            python3-setuptools \
            python3-pip \
        ; \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U awscli

RUN apt-get clean
```

The other option is to use Alpine distribution:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

RUN set -eux; \
        apk add python3 ; \
        pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U awscli
```

Sources:

- https://bitbucket.org/vodkaseledka/openjdk8-awscli
- https://bitbucket.org/vodkaseledka/openjdk8-awscli-alpine

Or you can get pre-builds from here:

- https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/savnn/openjdk8-awscli
- https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/savnn/openjdk8-awscli-alpine

Answer (score 0):

this work for me: create dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

RUN apk update;
RUN set -eux; \
        apk add python3 ; \
        pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U awscli; \
        pip3 install --upgrade pip;
RUN apk add groff
```

use `docker build . -t aws` then run: `docker run -it aws /bin/sh`